# regex match for string

Tags: regex

i have the following string:
@name{name:name}@

I'm looking for a regex pattern that will match that string (of course name can be anything)
the regex should also match cases where name:name can be name:name,name:name numerous times.

thanks in advance.

Comment: should the `name`s be identical?

Comment: name will be any word and they won't be identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@[^{]+\{[^:]+:[^},]+(,[^:]+:[^},]+)*\}@
```

the meaning of this regex is simple: always avoid match the upcoming delimiter.

let's say, at the beginning, `[^{]+` will match everything until the first `{`, so that the grab all the chars in between.

`[^:]+:[^},]+` matches the first occurrence in `{}`,

and `(,[^:]+:[^},]+)*` is the part which tries to match the optional comma separate part.

here is the test case in python:

```
>>> re.match(r'@[^{]+\{[^:]+:[^},]+(,[^:]+:[^},]+)*\}@', r'@table{name:tablea,partiton:id}@') is not None
True
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: can you please elaborate if @[^{]+\{[^:]+:[^},]+(,[^:]+:[^},]+)*\}@ refers to a case where 'name' will not be the same? - i can't seem to match my string with it - my string is @table{name:tablea,partiton:id}@

Answer (score 0):

Considering the `name` will remain same:

```
@([^\{]+)\{(\1:\1)(,\2)*\}@
```

Check: https://regex101.com/r/kX2fS0/2